# setinterval causing my app to crash

Tags: javascript, function, titanium, setinterval

Can anyone explain why this is causing my app to crash? It always crashes on the second iteration of the loop.

```
function FetchMetaData () {
alert("Am I being fired");  
}

var timer= setInterval(FetchMetaData(),10000);
```

Comment: There is no loop here... but by the time you've clicked ok on the alert box, the interval probably tried to call _the return value_ of `FetchMetaData`, which is undefined, which is not a function... also: interval? really? what _are_ you trying to do

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem Sorry I originally had a loop but I needed a break of ten seconds between every iteration so I switched to setInterval. I'm actually going to be calling a function which returns the meta data related to a song currently played on the radio. Then, based on what that function returns, I'm updating a label's text on my main screen, if the returned value is different to the label's text. I didn't include this as I couldn't even get the alert to occur every 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "crashing"; you're just calling the function once.  You should pass the function itself to `setInterval()`, not the result of *calling* the function:

```
var timer = setInterval(FetchMetaData, 10000);
```

When you write it as `FetchMeData()`, that means that the function should be called right then and there, and that whatever value it returns should be what's passed to `setInterval()`. Sometimes that makes sense, but in this case you need to pass a reference to your function.  You do that in JavaScript by simply using the name of the function *without* calling it.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'll look into it now, but my app is crashing

Comment: @user2363025 you need to be somewhat more specific than just "crashing".  How do you know it's "crashing"?  What exactly does that mean? What have you seen reported in the error console?

Comment: crashing as in the app gets force closed. Thanks anyway, it's fixed now